# is it possible to negate columns in the by parameter for data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to specify sum columns and group by the remaining columns.  It seemed like there is no way to negate columns in the by parameter like its possible for .SDcols.  Is that correct? I have found another way of doing it, but was wondering if I am missing some data.table magic.

```
a=data.table(a=c(1,3,1), b=c(2,2,3), c=c(5,6,7))

not_gp = c('b','c')
# this works but is not what I want!
a[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=not_gp,.SDcols =!not_gp]


# what I want, but doesn't work
a[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=!not_gp,.SDcols =not_gp]
# Error in !not_gp : invalid argument type
#does work
gp = names(a)[!names(a) %in% not_gp]
a[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=gp,.SDcols =not_gp]
# also works
a[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=gp]
```

Comment: Something like `a[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = setdiff(names(a), not_gp), .SDcols = not_gp]` ? Though no data table magic was used :(

Comment: `x[x %in% y]` is `intersect(x,y)` and, after your edit: `x[!x %in% y]` is `setdiff(x,y)` as noted in the last comment.

Comment: @Frank, sorry there was a typo in my code, so setdiff was my intention

Comment: Np, was just letting you know about the functions. Pretty sure there is no better way to do it than setdiff currently. You could ask UserXYZ to post as an answer if it works for you.

Comment: @User2321 please post as an answer.... am surprised that negation is not directly supported for by

Comment: @seanv507 honestly grouping by all-but-a-few columns doesn't seem like that common of an operation to warrant the dev time required to implement. You could define a function `\`!by\` = function(DT, x) setdiff(names(DT), x)` if you really want. And always feel free to submit an FR -- if there's sufficient momentum behind your proposal, it could be added later: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Comment: @seanv507 just did! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
a[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = setdiff(names(a), not_gp), .SDcols = not_gp]
```

Which gives you:

```
   a b  c
1: 1 5 12
2: 3 2  6
```